# Passing from a Wikipedia english page to the same page in another language (e. g. italian)

Tags: wikipedia, wiki

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass from a Wikipedia page in English to the same Wikipedia page in another language (e.g. Italian). I don't want to translate the English page in Italian, I want to see if there is the same page in Italian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Wikipedia explains how they handle languages and how to switch between languages on this page [List of Wikipedias](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Wikipedias).

*Each Wikipedia has a language code, which is used as a subdomain below wikipedia.org. Interlanguage links are sorted by that code as a prefix. The codes represent the language codes defined by ISO 639-1 and ISO 639-3, and the decision of which language code to use is usually determined by the IETF language tag policy*

### SHORT ANSWER

Change the 2 letter language `prefix` (e.g.`en`, `de`, `il`) to change to a different site language.

**`Example URL Variations`**
Note that there are often variations in the URL's from site to site, in addition to the language prefix.

Sample URL Variation 1
   **Stack Overflow** (*The Website*)

- English
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- German
  https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_(Website)
- Italian
  https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow_(sito)

Sample URL Variation 2
   **Stack Overflow** (*The Definition*)

- English
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow
- German
  https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- Italian
  https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

##### ACCURATELY DETERMINE ALTERNATE LANGUAGE URLS

What follows describes different approaches  for **mobile** vs. **desktop** versions of Wikipedia pages.  Wikipedia will, by default, try to serve you the appropriate version of the page based on the platform they detect.  There is, however, no reason you couldn't view **desktop** versions of pages on **mobile** devices, and vice versa.  The **mobile** vs. **desktop** distinction refers to the **coding** of the web page as opposed to the actual platform (device) used to access the page.

**MOBILE VERSION**
If you add `#/languages` to the end of a **mobile** <sup>**t**</sup> Wikipedia URL  you will get links to the page on other language sites.
<sub><sup>**t**</sup> Mobile URLs have `m` modifier in the path: https://en.`m`.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow</sub>

- *from*
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- *to*
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#/languages

**DESKTOP VERSION**
The method described for **mobile** versions  doesn't work for the **desktop** version of those pages.  For **desktop** versions of the page, a list of commonly selected languages exists in the left column of the page which link directly to the alternate language pages, in addition to a dynamic menu labeled **`## More`** which lists any languages remaining that are hidden (## = addt'l langs hidden).

Comment: Thank you a lot @BlindSpots

Answer (score 2):

There is a button that shows you the list of available languages. On desktop, it's located to the right of the title:

[image: icon + "N languages"]

On mobile, it is underneath the title (and at larger widths will say "Language" next to it):

[image: icon under "article"]

You can type the English name in the search box to find the language, even if it doesn't match the translated name (e.g. "Japanese" to get to "日本語").

The icon itself is the characters "文A", which is a [common symbol to indicate translations](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:%E6%96%87A). The character [文](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%96%87) means "a character, a letter" in Japanese.